# why do i get the error and ...?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, printing

In my program i declared a function `prototype` like :

`void callToPrint(LPTSTR , LPVOID , DWORD , string )`

But i get the following error due to this statement : `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'`

There are other errors also in the code which tell that the `function` does not take `4 arguments.`

*`(error C2660: 'callToPrint' : function does not take 4 arguments)`*

**Why do i get this error ? And how can i fix them ?**

*My second question is :*

- I have declared a variable `nameofPrinter` of type `LPTSTR` but when i write the statement  `getline( cin , nameOfPrinter )` , the error displayed is no instance of overloaded function `getline` matches the argument list. Then how can i receive the `nameOfPrinter` from the user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file needs to contain the following line:

```
#include <string>
```

The header file `string` contains the definition for the `string` class. Because that class is within the `std` namespace the function prototype needs to be:

```
void callToPrint(LPTSTR , LPVOID , DWORD , std::string );
```

Since you're using `LPTSTR` in the prototype you must be using Visual C++. If your project is set to use Unicode charset instead of multi-byte char set you need to adapt your types accordingly.

For Unicode charset:

```
std::wstring nameOfPrinter;
std::getline( std::wcin , nameOfPrinter );
```

Or, you could declare the type of your strings as:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> nameOfPrinter;
```

Unfortunately, such a templated class does not exist for switching between `cin` and `wcin`. So you'll have to resort to the preprocessor.

```
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
  #define _tcin wcin
#else
  #define _tcin cin
#endif

std::basic_string<TCHAR> nameOfPrinter;
std::getline( std::_tcin , nameOfPrinter );
```

Comment: You probably want `#ifdef _UNICODE`, but otherwise this is a good answer. Go with a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, and use that in your application instead.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Good catch, apparently the Windows SDK headers look for `UNICODE` while the crt looks for `_UNICODE`. So it looks like you should look for both.

Comment: Well, the CRT headers are always going to be there if you're including the Windows SDK headers. Checking for `_UNICODE` is the universal option. In 99% of cases, it won't matter. But there's a lot of questions about that 1% here on SO. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to First Question:**

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
```

You need to include the `string` header file in the header or source file where you are declaring the function, like:

```
 #include <string>
```

&

The `namespace std`; should be included in your source file 
like:

```
using namespace std;
```

Or
Alternatively, you should use:

```
std::string
```

**Answer to Second Question:**

`istream::getline()` is a function in the `istream` class with following overloaded versions:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

Obviously, it does not understand your defined type of `LPTSTR`, so it tells you that there is no matching function call which takes `LPTSTR` as an argument.

**How to resolve it?**
In the comments @Cody Gray, explains you the real problem and the solution is ofcourse as suggested to convert `LPTSTR` in a format so that it cam match the `istream::getline()` parameter, which essentialy means convert the string you have in `wchar_t*` to a `char*` by using **[wcstombs()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/wcstombs/)**

Comment: Obviously you haven't tried it *correctly*. This is the correct answer... Although I'd have written `using std::string;` and not even mentioned the possibility of `using namespace` :-)

Comment: and, did you put std:: before string in the function prototype?

Comment: @ Als then is there any other way of receiving the `nameOfPrinter` of type `LPTSTR`

Comment: @SuhailGupta: The problem lies in the fact that `LPTSTR` is conditionally defined depending on whether the program is compiled as Unicode. If so, `LPTSTR` is defined as `wchar_t*`. Otherwise, it is defined as `char*`. The catch is that all Win32 applications should now be compiled with Unicode defined. So `LPTSTR` does not match the function definition for `istream::getline()`, which takes a `char*` rather than a `wchar_t*`. You'll need to convert narrow characters to their wide representations in order for this to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

> But i get the following error due to this statement : error C2061:
>   syntax error : identifier 'string'

You need to `#include <string>` and either use `using namespace std;` or declare `string` as `std::string` to use the `string` class.

> the error displayed is no instance of overloaded function getline
>   matches the argument list.

The second parameter of `getline()` is a reference to `std::string`. [Apparently `LPTSTR` is not `std::string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use `std::string` instead.

<strike>Looks like you're developing GUI application. Why are you taking input using `cin`?</strike>

Comment: What makes it "look like" a GUI application to you? `LPTSTR` is conditionally defined in the Windows headers, depending on whether you're compiling the app as Unicode. So it's either `*char_t*` or `char*`. This type existed *long* before `std::string` was invented.

Comment: @cody gray: one of OP's tag is `visual-c++`.

Comment: Yes, you can create non-GUI applications in Visual C++. That's just Microsoft's name for its implementation of C++. There's nothing magical about it that restricts you to GUI applications. In particular, you can create console applications that run in a console window on the desktop. They don't display any UI.